# What is it called when the action doesnt affect the state in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

In reinforcement learning, is there a name for algorithms where the action taken doesnt affect the state? e.g armed bandit

Answer (score 6):

In the RL setting, [armed bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) are considered stateless, so naturally actions do not affect the state. There are just actions and rewards.

If you add a state, but the actions do not have an effect on what the next state will be, they are called [Contextual Bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit#Contextual_bandit). Contextual bandits have states, actions and rewards. Your state (or "context") may affect your action, but not the other way around, i.e. there are no transition rules like in a normal RL.